# jq json - select by key name

Tags: json, select, key, command-line-interface, jq

I'm using jq to try to parse some details from an AWS CLI query.
Example JSON:

```
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Key": "Name",
                            "Value": "db01"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "BackupResourceType",
                            "Value": "EC2"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "Role",
                            "Value": "db_edi01"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "OS",
                            "Value": "Ubuntu 18.04"
                        }
                    ],
```

The issue I'm running into is these tag values aren't in a consistent order.  Is there a way I can select the value where key=OS instead of selecting the specific array value?

`[.InstanceId, .State.Name, .Tags[1].Value, .Tags[0].Value, etc]`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: _"Is there a way I can select the value where key=OS..."_ -- The answer is in the question. Read about the [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) function of `jq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the niftiest way would be to use `from_entries`.  E.g. for the "OS" key:

```
.Tags | from_entries | .OS
```

More generally, but more verbosely, you could go with:

```
.Tags | first( .[] | select(.Key == "OS") | .Value)
```

or if you're concerned about the result if the specified key is not present:

```
.Tags | first( .[] | select(.Key == "OS") // {} | .Value)
```

---

Without seeing a complete sample, it's hard to say exactly what the most economical expression would be, but piggy-backing off your example, you could go with something like:

```
[.InstanceId, .State.Name] +
 [.Tags | from_entries | (.OS, .Role)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I'm trying to determine how I add your recommendation to the end of an existing array:
`.Reservations[2].Instances[0] | [.InstanceId, .State.Name, .PlatformDetails, .InstanceType, .PrivateDnsName, .PrivateIpAddress, .Placement.AvailabilityZone, .LaunchTime,  ...   .Tags | first( .[] | select(.Key == "OS") | .Value)`
I'm still new to this syntax and am missing something..

Comment: Just use parentheses judiciously.

Comment: Your last edit finally clicked for me.  Thank you!  That's exactly what I was looking for, really appreciate it!